# Getting error 'Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection' when using union and select together in EF Core 7

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I wrote a code that EF Core creates an expression for that looks like this:

```
DbSet<Reception>()
.Include(x => x.Employee)
.Include(x => x.ReceptionSignatures)
.Where(x => x.Employee.FirstName.Contains("mo"))
.Union(DbSet<Reception>()
    .Include(x => x.Employee)
    .Include(x => x.ReceptionSignatures)
    .Where(x => x.Employee.PersonelId.Contains("mo")))
.Union(DbSet<Reception>()
    .Include(x => x.Employee)
    .Include(x => x.ReceptionSignatures)
    .Where(x => x.Employee.LastName.Contains("mo")))
.Union(DbSet<Reception>()
    .Include(x => x.Employee)
    .Include(x => x.ReceptionSignatures)
    .Where(x => x.Employee.NationId.Contains("mo")))
.OrderBy(x => x.Employee.FirstName.CompareTo("mo") == 0 ? 0 : 1)
.Select(r => new ReceptionAllDTO{ 
    ReceptionId = r.Id, 
    NationId = r.Employee.NationId, 
    PersonelId = r.Employee.PersonelId, 
    FirstName = r.Employee.FirstName, 
    LastName = r.Employee.LastName, 
    Birthday = r.Employee.Birthday, 
    RecepDate = r.RecepDate, 
    Height = r.Height, 
    Weight = r.Weight, 
    ReceptionSignatures = r.ReceptionSignatures, 
}
)
```

In `Reception` entity, I have a relation to `Signature` like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Signature> ReceptionSignatures { get; set; }
```

but when EF Core wants to create a query for SQL, it throws this exception:

> Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection since either parent or the subquery doesn't project necessary information required to uniquely identify it and correctly generate results on the client side. This can happen when trying to correlate on keyless entity type. This can also happen for some cases of projection before 'Distinct' or some shapes of grouping key in case of 'GroupBy'. These should either contain all key properties of the entity that the operation is applied on, or only contain simple property access expressions.

Comment: Rewrite *your* LINQ query without `Union` (all your conditions are simple to be or'ed (`||`) in a single query `Where`). EF Core still has very limited support for `Concat` / `Union` queries, so in case you don't want to wait couple years for EF Core 8, 9 etc. who knows, take the above suggestion.

Comment: As mentioned by Ivan, rewrite query by using `||` operator, also you can remove ALL Includes.

Comment: Please clarify: is your query dynamically generated based on selected properties (FirstName, PersonelId, etc)?

Comment: @IvanStoev my query is created dynamically and is different for every table and I'm not able to dynamically create `or`s at the moment.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov exactly you're right. so what should I do?

Comment: I can't repro this issue anymore in EF7. Seems that it's fixed in later releases.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are querying for more data which is really not efficient. Its better to project your required columns using the `Select()` and then write a `Union`.

When writing the `Union` the number of columns Selected must be same as shown below from a code base i wrote  2 weeks ago and which works.

```
var billPaymentVoucherQuery = _context.Set<BillPaymentVoucher>().AsQueryable();
var billsQuery = _context.Set<Bill>().AsQueryable();
    
var anon_billsQuery = billsQuery.Where(w => w.InvoiceDate.Date <= filter.AsAtDate.Date)
                                            .Where(w => w.OperationalStatus == OperationalBillStatus.Approved &&
                                                        (
                                                          w.FinancialStatus == FinancialBillStatus.Pending ||
                                                          w.FinancialStatus == FinancialBillStatus.OnHold ||
                                                          w.FinancialStatus == FinancialBillStatus.PartiallyApproved ||
                                                          w.FinancialStatus == FinancialBillStatus.Approved
                                                        ))
                                            .Select(s => new
                                            {
                                                VendorName = s.VendorInvoice.Vendor!.Name,
                                                Type = "Bill",
                                                Date = s.InvoiceDate,
                                                Number = Convert.ToString(s.InvoiceNumber),
                                                Amount = s.LineItemTotal + s.VATAmount
                                            }).AsQueryable();
    
            var anon_billPaymentVoucherQuery = billPaymentVoucherQuery
                                              .Where(w => (
                                                           w.UpdatedOn.HasValue &&
                                                           w.UpdatedOn.Value.Date <= filter.AsAtDate.Date
                                                          )
                                                          ||
                                                          (
                                                           w.UpdatedOn.HasValue == false &&
                                                           w.CreatedOn.Date <= filter.AsAtDate.Date
                                                          ))
                                              .Where(w => w.BillPaymentVoucherStatus == BillPaymentVoucherStatus.Paid)
                                              .Select(s => new
                                              {
                                                  VendorName = s.PaymentApprovedBill.Bill.VendorInvoice.Vendor!.Name,
                                                  Type = "Payment",
                                                  Date = s.UpdatedOn ?? s.CreatedOn,
                                                  Number = Convert.ToString(s.PaymentApprovedBill.Bill.InvoiceNumber + " | " +
                                                                            s.PaymentVoucherNumber),
                                                  Amount = -s.PayAmount
                                              }).AsQueryable();
    
            var unionedQuery = anon_billsQuery.Union(anon_billPaymentVoucherQuery)
                                              .Where(w => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Type) || w.Type == filter.Type);
    
            int pageSize = 2;
            bool hasMoreRecords = true;
    
            
                var transactionData = await unionedQuery.OrderBy(w => w.VendorName)
                                                    .ThenBy(w => w.Date)
                                                    .Skip((paginator.PageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                                                    .Take(pageSize)
                                                    .ToListAsync(token);
```

Comment: Thanks, but my query is created dynamically and is different for every table. so my application doesn't know what to select for each table.
I think ef core should translate the code into the proper sql query when unions are used, so we don't have to select manually.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception when I was using more than two Unions() in a row like

query1.Union(query2).Union(query3)

When I changed it to nested unions it was working:

query1.Union(query2.Union(query3));

Comment: This sadly didn't work for me. Also, you have two query1 sets, are you sure you don't have a bug in the code that makes this work?